# Derefencing a cast

Tags: c, pointers

What does `*(uint16_t *)"200"` return? From what I understand, the `"200"` refers to a pointer to a character array, so the pointer refers to the `'2'` character, which in then converted to an integer via ascii characters, but I don't understand what the final `*` character does.

Comment: The cast treats the char array pointer as a pointer to an integer, the final asterisk dereferences the integer pointer, leaving you with the value it points to.

Answer (score 3):

Break the complex expression into pieces:

```
char const* a = "200";
uint16_t*   b = (uint16_t*)a;
uint16_t    c = *b;
```

`a` is a pointer to the initial character of the string literal (`'2'`).

When we obtain `b` via the cast, we say "pretend the pointed-to data is actually a `uint16_t` (or an array thereof).

When we dereference `b` to obtain `c`, we obtain "the `uint16_t` at address `b`."

So, it's reinterpreting the first two characters (two bytes, 16 bits) of the string literal (`"20"`), as a `uint16_t`.

Comment: So b converts, 20, which in binary would be 00110010'00110000, to a 16 bit decimal number, which would be 12748?

Comment: @JacobDenson Actually its 12338, assuming your computer has big endian.( very probable ) then the order of the interpretation of the bytes is reversed.

Comment: It should be mentioned that, if the address is not suitably aligned for `uint16_t`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard.